# Balling's paper on ABV full text?

Tags: alcohol-content

Can anyone tell me where to find the full text of Balling's article/book where his famous equation comes from? (I don't mind if it is in German).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't read German but from a bit of Googling I see references to "Die Bierbrauerei", though it looks like this appears in several works.

Regardless, [searching Google Scholar](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C36&q=%22Die+Bierbrauerei%22+Karl+Balling&btnG=) I found [this](https://books.google.com/books?hl=en&lr=&id=mZk5AAAAcAAJ&oi=fnd&pg=PA3&dq=%22Die+Bierbrauerei%22+Karl+Balling&ots=0IChpPV3Kh&sig=D-zGI_ertekvkrisj8mGoXv-D3E#v=onepage&q&f=false), which seems promising.  I'm not 100% sure if this is what you're looking for but there are other books/papers by Karl Balling in the search results that may be it.

Comment: Yes, it looks like that's it. Clearly your google-fu is better than mine. Thanks!